# Ubuntu and updating Docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run the latest stable version of docker and docker-compose.

I am following the instructions on https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

Apparently the current version of docker-compose is 1.7.

Yet, after running through the documentation, installing docker-engine, I then get:

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version: 1.4.0
```

And

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.11.1, build 5604cbe
```

When I try to update it, I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade docker-engine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... docker-engine is already the newest version.
Done
```

**Update**

This just keeps getting stranger. After trying all of the advice below, I now get this:

```
$ docker-compose -v
The program 'docker-compose' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install docker-compose
anton@Charles:~$ sudo apt-get install docker-compose
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
docker-compose is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How then can I update docker?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: Yes, I have done this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this stuff :

```
sudo sh -c "wget -qO- https://get.docker.io/gpg | apt-key add -"
sudo sh -c "echo deb http://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main\ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install lxc-docker
```

If this is not working, lets do it via third party :

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
$ sudo sh -c "echo deb https://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install lxc-docker
```

Comment: Thanks, however, when I do this, I get exactly the same result. The version is always `docker -v
Docker version 1.11.1, build 5604cbe
`

Comment: did u removed all docket stuff first ? `sudo apt-get remove docker*`
Follow this maybe
http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-upgrade-docker-1-7/

Comment: Yes, and now are reinstalling docker-engine, the compose version has gone down! `$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version: 1.3.1`

Comment: did you tried the official docs? coz this is weird :

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

Comment: Thanks Nishant. This brings docker to 1.9.1, and I have installed compose using https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/. Thanks again.

Comment: Doesn't work, my docker version was 1.9.1 now is the same version, I want to upgrade to the version 18.

Comment: It did not work for me. Instead, it uninstalled my docker and docker.io packages and replaced docker with an older version (docker-compose remained the same version). I had to install them again. Reported for Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 69):

Try this, it is quite simple:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade docker-ce
```

Results in the following

```
docker-ce is already the newest version.
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well, my previous *docker version* was 1.9.1 now is 18.06

Comment: Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701

Comment: This didn't work for me for ubuntu 18. tried to update from docker 20 to 23

Comment: Why `sudo apt-get upgrade docker-ce` instead of just `docker`? What is this "-ce" about?

Comment: @KvotheChibli docker community edition

Answer (score 59):

Since I lost half an hour on this, maybe it will help some people out there. 
What I had to do to upgrade my version is:

```
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.13.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" > ./docker-compose
sudo mv ./docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

Use [the last version of docker compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) instead of `1.13.0`.

Comment: This is upgrading `docker-compose` instruction, How about upgrade *docker version* to 18?

Comment: why not to download it directly to `curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.13.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" > /usr/bin/docker-compose` ?

Answer (score 2):

What you now have to do is to update docker-composer because your docker is up to date.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

> curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.7.0/docker-compose-`uname -s'-'uname -m' > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
>
> chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

Comment: When I try this I get `$ curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.7.0/docker-compose-uname -s-uname -m > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
curl: option -s-uname: is unknown`

Comment: I forgot the quotes Just follow it on the official site...https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.7.0/docker-compose 'uname -s'-'uname -m' > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

Comment: Now I get `curl: option -m: requires parameter`

Comment: Ok you are not so into console just install it with binaries

https://dl.bintray.com/docker-compose/master/

Comment: Please read the original post. I am using Ubuntu, and have been trying to follow official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem when you have docker installed as latest version and `docker-compose` is an old version.

Try `docker-compose -V`.  If it gives old version then  you have to uninstall via `pip`

```
pip uninstall docker-compose
```

Most of the time you uninstall with the same tool how you installed the old version.

It might give some error and partial uninstall.
Just restart Ubuntu and then install Docker from
https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/

Check the `docker compose` version again; hopefully it's the latest, and compatible with `docker`.

See the install docs for more install options and instructions.

Compose file format compatibility matrix

```
Compose file format Docker Engine
3.0 ; 3.1   1.13.0+
2.1         1.12.0+
2.0         1.10.0+
1.0         1.9.1+
Changes
```