# How to upgrade docker-compose to 2.0?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I get this error whenever I try to set up a development environment:

> ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml' service 'version' doesn't have
>   any configuration options. All top level keys in your
>   docker-compose.yml must map to a dictionary of configuration options.

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.5.2, build unknown
```

I'm told that I need to upgrade my docker-compose. But how can I upgrade it? I can't find any documentation about it.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I tried the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934675/ubuntu-and-updating-docker):

```
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.8.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" > ./docker-compose
sudo mv ./docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

After installing/ upgrading, I get this error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/docker-compose: Permission denied
```

And I can run any container anymore!

```
$ docker-compose --version
bash: /usr/bin/docker-compose: Permission denied
```

and:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
bash: /usr/bin/docker-compose: Permission denied
```

Any ideas???

**EDIT 2:**

I tried this from the docker [site](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/):

```
 $ curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.9.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

 chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

I still get the permission error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/docker-compose: Permission denied
```

Why!???

**EDIT 3:**

> Note: If you get a “Permission denied” error, your /usr/local/bin
>   directory probably isn’t writable and you’ll need to install Compose
>   as the superuser. Run sudo -i, then the two commands below, then exit.

So, I have tried:

```
$ sudo -i
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.9.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
exit
```

Then:

```
$ docker-compose --version
bash: /usr/bin/docker-compose: Permission denied
```

No good...

Comment: Try with `sudo`

Comment: sudo what then?

Answer (score 2):

First,

```
chmod -R 755 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

and replace old version form `/usr/bin/` with command:

```
mv /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to add the docker group to your user :

`$ sudo groupadd docker`

And then:

`$ sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)`

[source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/)

Comment: Did you try wit $USER instead?