# Upgrade docker in Unbutu16.04

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I have docker version 18.09.5 in Ubuntu16.05.

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.5
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        e8ff056
 Built:             Thu May  9 23:18:36 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.5
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.4
  Git commit:       e8ff056
  Built:            Thu May  9 22:53:57 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

I need to install nvidia-docker2 and the error is

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-docker2 : Depends: docker-ce (= 5:18.09.7~3-0~ubuntu-xenial) but it is not installable or
                           docker-ee (= 5:18.09.7~3-0~ubuntu-xenial) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So need to upgrade to 18.09.7.

I followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934675/ubuntu-and-updating-docker) for update. But it looked, it is not doing right.
So I aborted as follow.

```
sudo aptitude install lxc-docker
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aufs-tools{a} lxc-docker lxc-docker-1.9.1{ab} 
0 packages upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,590 kB of archives. After unpacking 30.6 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lxc-docker-1.9.1 : Conflicts: docker.io but 18.09.5-0ubuntu1~16.04.2 is installed and it is kept back.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:
1)     docker.io                   



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     lxc-docker [Not Installed]                         
2)     lxc-docker-1.9.1 [Not Installed]                   



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] q
Abandoning all efforts to resolve these dependencies.
Abort.
```

So for my case, what is the right way to install nvidia-docker2?

Do I need to upgrade docker or how to upgrade?

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/857#issuecomment-439586831

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-do-i-install-20-if-im-not-using-the-latest-docker-version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved.
Followed this [link](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/).

The trick was we can see multiple repositories using

```
apt-cache madison docker-ce
```

Then 18.09.7 version was chosen to install.

Now nvidia-docker-2 is installed.